# How to render inline code example of handlebars code in VuePress

Tags: handlebars.js, vuepress

Unsure where to ask as I'm not 100% sure if this is a bug or intended or if I'm just missing something, but I'm currently writing some documentation (using VuePress) for a platform that uses handlebars.

I've found if I put handlebars markup within a inline code block, for example:

```
This can be very useful as an alternative to using the regular partial `{{> @name }}` helper to import sub-components.
```

with this I get the error:

```
invalid expression: Unexpected token > in
_s(> @name)
Raw expression: {{> @name }}
```

However, if i just simply do something like:

```
Here is an example `{{ name }}`
```

I get no errors, however, whatever is inside the {{ }} doesn't render on the front-end

Am I missing something or is there a suggested method of getting around this?

Thanks in advance

*Note: This only happens in inline code examples, it works fine in full code blocks using the standard triple backtick approach*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing this problem... The solution was right in front of me here - https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#escaping